# MongoDB - How to update if and only if all ids are matching inside a list's object

Tags: mongodb

Lets say I have an Object in MongoDB that looks like this:

```
"obj":
{
    "list":
    [
       { "_id": "123" },
       { "_id": "456" },
    ],

    "result": 42
}
```

Lets say I have an Event Object (happens to be in Kotlin, but do not mind the programming language):

```
 class Event(val ids: Set<String>, val newResult: Int)
```

How to construct an update query in MongoDB to set the `result` if and only if the `ids` in the Event Object match the `ids` inside the list.

Comment: try [$all](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) operator to match all ids

Comment: I thought the $all operator matches an array field? If so, is there any possibility to transform the `id`s' inside the List into a single Set and then somehow compare that against the Event Set?

Comment: it will auto set when condition match see [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RB17p16YSqy)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I had to add $size into the game, otherwise it will match subsets. See playground [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/uvdgv-P-iW_). But now it works like a charm. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.